# Get chips delete event in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my application I have used chips for contact selection using [Chips](https://github.com/kpbird/chips-edittext-library) . And it is working fine.When user adds a contact ,its id is saved in an arraylist. the problem is when user deletes a contact using delete button in soft keyboard how will I can delete its id from arraylist. How can I link achip to its id.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

following code is used for creating chips.

```
public void setChips() {
    if (friends_multiautocomplete_tv.getText().toString().contains(";")) // check
                                                                            // semicolon
                                                                            // in
                                                                            // string
    {

        SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(
                friends_multiautocomplete_tv.getText());
        // split string with semicolon
        String chips[] = friends_multiautocomplete_tv.getText().toString()
                .trim().split(";");
        int x = 0;
        // loop will generate ImageSpan for every name separated by
        // semicolon
        for (String c : chips) {
            // inflate chips_edittext layout
            LayoutInflater lf = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            TextView textView = (TextView) lf.inflate(
                    R.layout.chips_edittext, null);
            textView.setText(c); // set text
            Typeface tfNormal = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                    "SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf");
            textView.setTypeface(tfNormal);
            // capture bitmapt of genreated textview
            int spec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0,
                    MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            textView.measure(spec, spec);
            textView.layout(0, 0, textView.getMeasuredWidth(),
                    textView.getMeasuredHeight());
            Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(textView.getWidth(),
                    textView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(b);
            canvas.translate(-textView.getScrollX(), -textView.getScrollY());
            textView.draw(canvas);
            textView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap cacheBmp = textView.getDrawingCache();
            Bitmap viewBmp = cacheBmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
            textView.destroyDrawingCache(); // destory drawable
            // create bitmap drawable for imagespan
            BitmapDrawable bmpDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(viewBmp);
            bmpDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, bmpDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                    bmpDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
            // create and set imagespan
            ssb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(bmpDrawable), x, x + c.length(),
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            x = x + c.length() + 1;
        }
        // set chips span
        friends_multiautocomplete_tv.setText(ssb);
        // move cursor to last
        friends_multiautocomplete_tv
                .setSelection(friends_multiautocomplete_tv.getText()
                        .length());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling to understand your question and I fail to see how your code sample is related to your question of "how will I can delete its id from arraylist" but in general you'll want to iterate through your array list checking if the current item matches the ID you are trying to delete:

If you are trying to match multiple items, then you could create a structure which associates two or more variables together. You can then either store this structure instead if storing your IDs or have an additional structure which assists you to match names to IDs. For example:

```
public class DataStructure{
    public String id;
    public String name;
}

ArrayList<DataStructure> arrayList = null;
String name;

for(DataStructure item : arrayList) {
    if(item.name.equals(name)) {
        arrayList.remove(item);
        break;
    }
}
```

Please note that in any case, if you are trying to match names to IDs, it's very possible that more than one ID will match to a name.

Comment: Actually I am just adding the name in Edit text and its id in an arraylist.When the user deletes the name I want to delete it id.